# Regex expression for -10.01 to10.12 including 0

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for regex expression which takes -10 to 10 with 2 decimal numbers upto 12. means cases passed are -10.01 to -10.11 for 10 years and 11 months.
I was able to make a regex for -10 to 10 but adding decimal till .11 was not able to figure out If somebody can help that would be great.

cases passed -
0
1
10.01
10.00
10.11
-10.00
-10.01
10.12 
-10.00
10

cases should fail - 
10.12
10.13
-10.13
11
-11
-10.13

Comment: Have you tried anything, SO isnt' a code writing service. Also, does it have to be a regex?

Comment: ^-?([1-9]|1[0])$ is the regex for -10 to 10. Yes it has to be regex as i have to hard code it. now im not getting how to make it decimal upto 2 numbers limiting till .11 only.

Comment: Yeah, just converting to a number and testing that to see if it's in range would be a lot simpler. Could still use a RE to enforce exactly 2 digits after the decimal point if present, though.

Comment: "*it has to be regex as i have to hard code it*" doesn't make sense. It's far easier to validate a number range as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that values such as 9.08 and -5.04 are also valid? In that case this regex: `^-?(10|[0-9])(\.(0[0-9]|1[01]))?$` will match the values you want. The first part looks for a number from -10 to 10; the second part looks for an optional decimal part which can be something from 00-09 or 10 or 11.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GrDlOb/2)